# How to Add delete button to php result

Tags: php

I need your support to check my code I want to add delete button with my php result to delete specific id from the table.

I tried the code below but it doesn't work with my!

Check my code :

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   //Creates a loop to loop through results
                        echo "
                            <tr><td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $row['sendDateandTime'] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $row['visitorName'] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $row['visitorPhone'] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $row['visitorEmail'] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $row['visitorMsg'] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $row['visitorCMethod'] . "</td>
                            <td class='' id=''>
                            <td class="contact-delete">
                                <form action='delete.php?name="<?php echo $contact['name']; ?>"' method="post">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $contact['name']; ?>">
                                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="<i class='fa fa-trash fa-lg'></i>">
                                </form>
                            </td>

                            </tr>";  //$row['index'] the index here is a field name
                        }
```

I have got this way from here but I dont not know where is the mistake the mistake is

```
<td class="contact-delete">
                                <form action='delete.php?name="<?php echo $contact['name']; ?>"' method="post">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $contact['name']; ?>">
                                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="<i class='fa fa-trash fa-lg'></i>">
                                </form>
                            </td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your entire `echo` string is wrong due to double quotes `"` and single quotes `'` incorrectly used.  Also, you have `<?php echo..` inside the string, which is already in php tags, that will definitely produce an error.

Rewrite it like this:

```
   echo '<tr>
            <td>' . $row['id'] . '</td>
            <td>' . $row['sendDateandTime'] . '</td>
            <td>' . $row['visitorName'] . '</td>
            <td>' . $row['visitorPhone'] . '</td>
            <td>' . $row['visitorEmail'] . '</td>
            <td>' . $row['visitorMsg'] . '</td>
            <td>' . $row['visitorCMethod'] . '</td>
            <td class="" id=""></td>
            <td class="contact-delete">
                <form action="delete.php?name=' . $contact['name'] . '" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="' . $contact['name'] . '">
                    <button type="submit" name="submit">
                        <i class="fa fa-trash fa-lg"></i>
                    </button>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>';
```

Comment: Dear I tried to use the same but the browser showed server Error

Comment: What do you mean? When do you see "Server Error"? when you loaded the page? or when you clicked on the delete button?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing :

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="<i class='fa fa-trash fa-lg'></i>">
```

With :

```
<button type="submit" name="submit">
    <i class="fa fa-trash fa-lg"></i>
</button>
```

You can't put an HTML tag in an attribute.

Comment: yes but how I can assigns the name value  to the submission, because the code I made is let the page get error

Comment: In the name attribute, like You did, and so do I